# command for expanding data in r

Tags: r

I have some data:

```
 Length(cm) Frequency
   1          5 
   2          2 
   3          3
   4          5
```

Is there a way to expand these numbers in R without typing them out manually, so I can work out the std error of the mean for length, so I have a dataset like:

```
  1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

which I can then work on? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `rep`.

```
> l <- 1:4
> f <- c(5,2,3,5)
> rep(l,f)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: Very nice! I never realized `rep` could use vectors like that.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using `rep` to replicate the observations you could also use the `wtd.mean` and `wtd.var` functions in the `Hmisc` package to compute the weighted summaries without expanding (this will be better if the expanded vector would take up a large portion of memory).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a dataframe:

```
sd(rep(data$length, data$freq))
```